# C# How to loop through Progress Bar perfectly

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, logic

How do you perfectly loop through a progress bar if you do not know the total length.
When I tried this my loop ended first then progress bar would be like 40%

```
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
                Convert(files[i]);
            }
```

Comment: you want a percentage

Comment: @Sayse You forgot the `* 100`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting

```
progressBar1.Maximum = files.Length;
```

before your loop

[MSDN - ProgressBar.Maximum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx)

Comment: +1 - Didn't know about this but its a novel approach (edited question to include the research link)